# How to import js file into svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I am building an app in svelte and I have a helper.js file inside /src folder where I am going to put helper functions.

I am trying to import the helper.js file into the GetData.svelte file:

## GateData.svelte:

```
<script>
  import Helper from "./helper.js";

  let helper = new Helper();

</script>
```

## helper.js:

```
class Helper {
    constructor() {
        console.log("hello world");
    }
}
```

## main.js:

```
import App from './App.svelte';


const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
});

export default app;
```

However, the error message I get is:

==>> Uncaught ReferenceError: Helper is not defined (main.js 6)

Do I have to import the helper.js file in the main.js as well?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You need to export. Use `export default class Helper`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export your class in **helper.js**:

```js
export class Helper {
    // ...
}
```

and then import it in **main.js** as

```js
import { Helper } from "./helper.js";
```

Or, if you only want to export this one class from the helper file, you can use

```js
export default class Helper {
    // ...
}
```

and import as you currently do:

```js
import Helper from "./helper.js";
```

Comment: Default just means "the default export", it doesn't necessarily mean the only export.

Comment: @Constantin Thank you very much for your answer. I did the way you suggested using the `export default class Helper {
    // ...}` and `import Helper from "./helper.js";` into main.js. Error message: `[!] Error: Could not resolve './helper.js' from src/main.js` ... I will keep trying. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I know, the wording is strange/ambiguous. Of course you could even use both, named and default export. I just wanted to show both.

Comment: @Hwebservices the helper file is located at src/helper.js?

Comment: @ConstantinGroß oh that was the issue... When I created the helper.js file I placed it on a parent folder... moved it and now it works perfectly! Thank you very much